# Android Kotlin Icon / Image variable

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class and need to save images/icons as variable. So I can put them into an ImageView later. Does anybody know, how to do that? My images/icons are in "drawable". For example "ic_delete".

Here my data class:

```
data class Category(
    val id: EnumCategories,
    val name: String,
    val itemType: EnumTypes?,
    val icon: Image
)

val categories = listOf(

    Category(EnumCategories.CATEGORY01, "CATEGORY01", null, -> Here should be my image <-),
    Category(EnumCategories.CATEGORY02, "CATEGORY02", EnumTypes.TYPE1, -> Here should be my image <-),
    Category(EnumCategories.CATEGORY03, "CATEGORY03", EnumTypes.TYPE2, -> Here should be my image <-)
)
```

Maybe I should use Bitmap instead of Image? Nevertheless, I don´t know how to put the images/icon into the List.

If I have the image/icon ressource in my list, I would use something like this to show the image:

```
imageView.setImageResource(categories[0].icon)
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `val icon: Int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data class Category(
    val id: EnumCategories,
    val name: String,
    val itemType: EnumTypes?,
    val icon: Int
)

val categories = listOf(

    Category(EnumCategories.CATEGORY01, "CATEGORY01", null, R.drawable.ic_delete),
    Category(EnumCategories.CATEGORY02, "CATEGORY02", EnumTypes.TYPE1, R.drawable.something),
    Category(EnumCategories.CATEGORY03, "CATEGORY03", EnumTypes.TYPE2, R.drawable.something_else)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`setImageResourse`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) take an `int` so you can use int

```
data class Category(
    val id: EnumCategories,
    val name: String,
    val itemType: EnumTypes?,
    val icon: Int
)
```

and save images as

```
val categories = listOf(

    Category(EnumCategories.CATEGORY01, "CATEGORY01", null, R.mipmap.ic_icon),
    ,...,..
)
```